# Are there any sample CVs to look at?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs, cv

I've noticed that the job postings in Career Overflow range from formal and factual to casual and flippant.  This along with the cv field prompts makes me think I can loosen up a tiny bit on my CV.  However, I don't want to be so flippant that I turn off possible employers.  Are there any sample CVs available that I can view to show me what levels of "cool" are acceptable?  I realize this is a subjective thing and varies from employer to employer.  But I surely hope that employers who post jobs asking for ninjas and rock stars don't frown on CVs that use the same type of language!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just search :

```
CV -"file -your" site:careers.stackoverflow.com
```

[It shows all CVs](http://www.google.com/search?q=CV+-%22file+-your%22+site:careers.stackoverflow.com&hl=en&lr=&as_qdr=all&ei=ZQwtTLPeH4eglAff2qTFCQ&start=0&sa=N&filter=0) that have ever been linked to (No other search term necessary).

Comment: Updated to remove extraneous results from the job postings. Now it's all CVs, all the time!

Comment: Your google-fu is strong, grasshopper.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  All good answers, so I just picked the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a google search for careers to see what different CVs are out there.

Try:

```
site:careers.stackoverflow.com/ john
site:careers.stackoverflow.com/ mike
site:careers.stackoverflow.com/ [Basically any common name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Carrie, we do have a sample CV here: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/community

I agree with the above that looking at others' CV is a good way to go as well.